# Search sqlite3 table for an integer using C++

Tags: c++11, sqlite

I have an sqliteCpp wrapper for my sqlite3 and was wondering if there is a query to search for integer in 'Symcod' columns as shown below:

```
sym = 100;
SQLite::Statement query(db, "SELECT Symcod FROM RawData WHERE EXISTS Symcod = sym");
```

but this gives me an Syntax error. Is there a way I can search the table for a integer using a variable name?

Answer (score 0):

The sqlitecpp [documentation](https://srombauts.github.io/SQLiteCpp/) suggests

```
// Compile a SQL query, containing one parameter (index 1)
SQLite::Statement   query(db, "SELECT * FROM test WHERE size > ?");

// Bind the integer value 6 to the first parameter of the SQL query
query.bind(1, 6);

// Loop to execute the query step by step, to get rows of result
while (query.executeStep())
{
    //.... do stuff with e.g. query.getColumn()
}
```

So you would construct your query using a `?` for the variable, then do `query.bind(1,sym)`